# Can I ask for a luggage transfer at the transfer check in counter in Taipei?

Tags: luggage, international-travel, emirates, taipei, korean-air

I'm taking a flight from Seoul to Taipei (on Korean Air) and then another one from Taipei to Paris (on Emirates) in August. The flights are on different airlines and booked with different reservations. I know that usually I would have to get my luggage at Taipei and check in again for the next flight, but due to certain circumstances, I will not be able to get a transit visa to fetch my luggage.

A contact told me that if I asked at the check-in counter in Seoul, they would be able to register my luggage for a transfer to my next flight, but I'm not sure yet if I can fully trust that. Has anyone ever been in this situation? Are they really able to ask for a transfer?

Comment: You can always ask, but whether they can actually do it will depend on whether Korean and Emirates have an interlining agreement.  Contact KAL and ask, it's the only way to find out.

Comment: This is a question for flyertalk.com. KE does have a luggage interline agreement with EK, so what you ask is technically and legally possible, but whether the check in agent will be willing to do this is up to the company policy.

Comment: Paid account of [expertflyer](https://www.expertflyer.com/) shows all interling agreement.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the airport and the airline. This is Korean Air's official statement on this:

https://www.koreanair.com/content/koreanair/global/en/traveling/baggage-services.html#transfer-procedures

You will need to ask Korean Air directly at the counter. If they say yes, then it should. With that said, if you check it in, the counter representative should remind and inform you of whether you need to pick it up and recheck it.